# Opening a suggested video using the same player instead of in YT

Tags: youtube

I put a video player using the latest iFrame API from YouTube inside a website, however when I click a suggested video, instead of reusing the same player, it opens YouTube instead.

I didn't find any options to not make it go to YouTube each time, is there any?.

Answer (score 0):

I used iframe API of youtube last month. I sometimes faced the same issue. But the issue was resolved by creating a iframe from the javascript. Please follow the below steps. I hope this will solve your problem.

Place a tag in your web page and write a javascript as shown below:

1 . Add a div element with id = "player" in your webpage.

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

In the Javascript part:
2. Add a script to load iframe player API

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

3.. Create an iframe.

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '320', //You can change height and width as needed
        width: '480',
        videoId: [video ID you want to load],
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            'onPlaybackQualityChange': onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange,
            'onPlaybackRateChange': onPlayerPlaybackRateChange,
            'onError': onPlayerError,
            'onApiChange': onPlayerApiChange,
        }
    });
}
```

4. You can handle events by using the below functions.

   function onPlayerStateChange(event){};
   function onPlayerReady(event){};
   function onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange(playbackQuality){};
   function onPlayerPlaybackRateChange(playbackRate){};
   function onPlayerError(e){};
   function onPlayerApiChange(){};

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: How is that going to fix the issue of not opening a suggested video link in the YouTube page?. I only see copypasted code of how to create an iFrame.

Comment: Suggested video cannot be loaded in your iframe. Unless you load your iframe again with that suggested video ID.